# Inject a dll file to UWP

Tags: c++, uwp, hook

I make simple a UWP app and a desktop app. This code inject the ConsoleApplication1.dll file to the desktop is normal, but I cannot inject to UWP app.
I have two question :
Why this code cannot inject to UWP app? 
and How fix it?

This code inject a DLL file

```
#include "pch.h"
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <windows.h>
#include <Tlhelp32.h>

using std::vector;
using std::string;

int main(void)
{
while (true)
{
    vector<string>processNames;
    PROCESSENTRY32 pe32;
    pe32.dwSize = sizeof(PROCESSENTRY32);
    HANDLE hTool32 = CreateToolhelp32Snapshot(TH32CS_SNAPPROCESS, NULL);
    BOOL bProcess = Process32First(hTool32, &pe32);
    if (bProcess == TRUE)
    {
        while ((Process32Next(hTool32, &pe32)) == TRUE)
        {
            processNames.push_back(pe32.szExeFile);
            if (strcmp(pe32.szExeFile, "ConsoleApplication4.exe") == 0 || strcmp(pe32.szExeFile, "UWP.exe") == 0)
            {
                printf("Hooked %s, %d \n", pe32.szExeFile, pe32.th32ProcessID);
                char* DirPath = new char[MAX_PATH];
                char* FullPath = new char[MAX_PATH];
                GetCurrentDirectory(MAX_PATH, DirPath);
                sprintf_s(FullPath, MAX_PATH, "%s\\..\\ConsoleApplication1\\ConsoleApplication1.dll", DirPath);
                FILE *pFile;
                if (fopen_s(&pFile, FullPath, "r") || !pFile)
                {
                    OutputDebugString("[Hook] File name or file does not exist");
                    OutputDebugString(FullPath);
                    return -1;
                }
                fclose(pFile);

                HANDLE hProcess = OpenProcess(PROCESS_ALL_ACCESS, FALSE, pe32.th32ProcessID);
                LPVOID LoadLibraryAddr = (LPVOID)GetProcAddress(GetModuleHandle("kernel32.dll"), "LoadLibraryA");
                LPVOID LLParam = (LPVOID)VirtualAllocEx(hProcess, NULL, strlen(FullPath), MEM_RESERVE | MEM_COMMIT, PAGE_READWRITE);

                bool result = WriteProcessMemory(hProcess, LLParam, FullPath, strlen(FullPath), NULL);
                CreateRemoteThread(hProcess, NULL, NULL, (LPTHREAD_START_ROUTINE)LoadLibraryAddr, LLParam, NULL, NULL);

                CloseHandle(hProcess);
                delete[] DirPath;
                delete[] FullPath;

                OutputDebugString("[Hook] Hooked success");

                system("pause");

                return 0;
            }
        }
    }
    CloseHandle(hTool32);
}
return 0;
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 6):

DLL injecting UWP apps is no different than injecting Win32 programs; the same techniques and generic DLL injectors will work for UWP apps. However, if one simply tries to inject any regular DLL into a UWP app, the DLL likely won't load. The reason for this is because the ALL APPLICATION PACKAGES group must have read & execute permissions for the DLL being injected.

To set these permissions manually: right click on the DLL, go into properties, go to the security tab, hit Edit, click Add, type "ALL" in the dialog that pops up and hit okay. On English systems, this will add ALL APPLICATION PACKAGES to the list of permissions with read/execute enabled by default; for non-English systems, the group will be named something different.

https://www.unknowncheats.me/forum/general-programming-and-reversing/177183-basic-intermediate-techniques-uwp-app-modding.html

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

This is by design for UWP processes. The UWP appcontainer does not allow dynamically loading code that wasn't part of the deployment package.

Comment: Have you any idea inject a DLL file to UWP app?

Comment: It's not possible to do that. But if you can expand your question and explain what you are really trying to accomplish we may be able to suggest an alternative solution. For example, you could add a desktop extension to your UWP package, which can then load and inject a DLL in its process. Not sure if that would fit your scenario though. Anyway, to learn more about adding a desktop extension to your UWP, I have a tutorial here: https://stefanwick.com/2018/04/06/uwp-with-desktop-extension-part-1/

Comment: Thanks, this tutorial is very good, I read it before, but it not helpful for me. I'm writing detour an address with MS-Detours in one file DLL and trying to inject it into a UWP app https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/30140/API-Hooking-with-MS-Detours.

Comment: @StefanWickMSFT , I want to expand the question and explain what I am trying to accomplish: I want to intercept any application (both Desktop & UWP) when it ask to access the Mic./Webcam and prompt the user with my customed dialog. I don't want to use the consent store direction; I rather prefer a method that is common to both Desktop & UWP applications. Can you suggest me an alternative solution?

Comment: I don't know if there is a way to do what you want to do, and I don't work in Windows anymore. I'd suggest you open a new question based on the details in your comment.