# C++/CX UWP Windows Desktop APIs not found

Tags: windows, dll, uwp, code-injection

I'm creating a UWP application that will allow me to inject a DLL into an application. When using Windows API functions, UWP seems to think the functions are undefined.

I've looked online for DLL source codes but none of them really use UWP. I've tried using only the injection source code from here: https://github.com/saeedirha/DLL-Injector. I suspect the reason why UWP isn't identifying the functions is because it isn't in the right namespace. I could be wrong but I suspect this is the reason why.

```
#include <ctype.h>
#include <Windows.h>
#include <tlhelp32.h>
#include <Shlwapi.h>
#include <tchar.h> 
#pragma comment(lib, "Shlwapi.lib")
#pragma comment(lib, "user32.lib")
bool InjectDLL(const int& pid, const std::string& DLL_Path)
{


long dll_size = DLL_Path.length() + 1;


HANDLE hProc = OpenProcess(PROCESS_ALL_ACCESS, FALSE, pid);



if (hProc == NULL)
{
    //cerr << "[!]Fail to open target process!" << endl;
    return false;
}
//cout << "[+]Opening Target Process..." << endl;

LPVOID MyAlloc = VirtualAllocEx(hProc, NULL, dll_size, MEM_COMMIT, PAGE_EXECUTE_READWRITE);
if (MyAlloc == NULL)
{
    //cerr << "[!]Fail to allocate memory in Target Process." << endl;
    return false;
}

//cout << "[+]Allocating memory in Targer Process." << endl;
int IsWriteOK = WriteProcessMemory(hProc, MyAlloc, DLL_Path.c_str(), dll_size, 0);
if (IsWriteOK == 0)
{
    //  cerr << "[!]Fail to write in Target Process memory." << endl;
    return false;
}
//cout << "[+]Creating Remote Thread in Target Process" << endl;

DWORD dWord;
LPTHREAD_START_ROUTINE addrLoadLibrary = (LPTHREAD_START_ROUTINE)GetProcAddress(LoadLibrary("kernel32"), "LoadLibraryA");
HANDLE ThreadReturn = CreateRemoteThread(hProc, NULL, 0, addrLoadLibrary, MyAlloc, 0, &dWord);
if (ThreadReturn == NULL)
{
    //cerr << "[!]Fail to create Remote Thread" << endl;
    return false;
}

if ((hProc != NULL) && (MyAlloc != NULL) && (IsWriteOK != ERROR_INVALID_HANDLE) && (ThreadReturn != NULL))
{
    //cout << "[+]DLL Successfully Injected :)" << endl;
    return true;
}

return false;
```

}

I expect there to be no error messages when compiling but I actually get:

C3861   'VirtualAllocEx': identifier not found

C3861   'WriteProcessMemory': identifier not found

C3861   'LoadLibrary': identifier not found

C3861   'CreateRemoteThread': identifier not found

Answer (score 0):

Please have a look a stefan's answer from this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52833300/inject-a-dll-file-to-uwp):

"This is by design for UWP processes. The UWP appcontainer does not allow dynamically loading code that wasn't part of the deployment package."

Comment: I think you got it reversed. My intent is to create a UWP that can inject dlls into win32 apps. Not the other way around. Unless it also applies this was as well?

Comment: @RichardWei Your code is directly C++ code and can I confirm that you are using the above code in a C++/CX UWP project. If so, you are still trying to access dll from UWP container. And for the API issue, UWP support only parts of the API, see this [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/win32-and-com/win32-and-com-for-uwp-apps). You have to read [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/porting/how-to-use-existing-cpp-code-in-a-universal-windows-platform-app?view=vs-2019) to understand how you can use your exist C++ code.

Comment: @RichardWei Actually I think I need to understand what you are trying to do. Do you mean you are trying to call a UWP dll from your win32 app? What is the meaning of create a UWP that can inject dlls to Win32 app?

Comment: I'm making my own DLL injector for a game emulator project and I'm familiar with UWP. So that's why I'm using UWP.

Comment: @RichardWei Hmmmm. I'm still not so clear about what you are trying to do since lack of details. But I recommend that you switch to use Win32 app or we can say common desktop technology to do this to avoid the limitation.

Comment: @RichardWei Glad to know that.