# Dll injection works on some processes, but not on others

Tags: c++, dll, code-injection

My problem is the following: If there are more processes of the same name with different process IDs, like in the case of Spotify, I only can inject my DLL into them, but one. None of the functions fail. I monitor the modules of the exe, and my dll don't show up in the case of that one exe.

My injector seems to work on 64 bit and 32 bit processes. I tested it on two programs I wrote (one 64, the other 32 bit), and notepade.exe. It injects to Spotify and ***parts*** of other applications too.

This one exe, in the case of the process that I'm actually trying to inject into, falls under the same category: more exe files, same name, can inject into all of them but one - the one I actually need to. It also doesn't inject into Calculator.exe.

Side note: I tried dll injectors. They also fail on the ones I can't inject into, and succeed on the ones that I do too.

What am I missing about this?

Sample code:

```
HANDLE hProc = OpenProcess(PROCESS_ALL_ACCESS, false, processID);
void* location = VirtualAllocEx(hProc, 0, MAX_PATH, MEM_COMMIT | MEM_RESERVE , PAGE_READWRITE);
WriteProcessMemory(hProc, location, dllPath, strlen(dllPath) + 1, 0);
HANDLE hThread = CreateRemoteThread(hProc, 0, 0, (LPTHREAD_START_ROUTINE)LoadLibraryA, location, 0, 0);
```

(I removed error handling and handle closing for the sake of simplicity, this is code that works, as described above)

Comment: What does "doesn't work" consist of?  I see 4 functions, which one fails?  (believe it or not, errors have meaning!)

Comment: Thank your for pointing out whats missing from the question. Added the required information. Any ideas now?

Comment: You do realize that for this to work both the injector and the dll you inject must match the bitness of the target process?

Comment: Of course. I suspect the answer is less obvious.

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is likely you're trying to inject your DLL into a UWP app. Refer to this thread for a solution. [Inject a dll file to UWP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52833300/inject-a-dll-file-to-uwp)